# Pictures I can not find

Tags: windows-vista, search

i have saved pictures off an instant chat, it says they are in Joint Photograpic experts group and that they are jpg.  Where do  I find them, can not find them anywhere on my computer

Comment: i think "join photographic experts group" is just the acronym expansion of JPEG, which is the file format.

Comment: @quack quixote: sherlock would be very proud of you :)

Comment: @akira: well yeah, but what does holding my liquor have to do with anything? :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use window's built in search feature.

Start -> Search, select type = .jpg or .jpeg, and click search. It should be able to find every .jpg image and let you browse through them.

Comment: +1. Also, the list may be quite long. To help find them in the list you can sort the results by Date Modified if you don't know their saved names but you do know roughly when you saved them.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/). It's a fantastically fast searcher based on a few characters of the file name and the file type. Since you don't know the file name a bit of detective work might be in order, perhaps by restricting the search to your folder (or program files, or temp), then sorting by date (this might take some time). You can then search (visually, by opening) or look for the correct time and date. Then "open folder" and you'll probably find all the .jpegs of that session.

My guess is that they'll be in "program files", in a sub folder of your IM or web browser, start there.

Comment: vista/win7 does not allow applications saving/altering files in *Program Files"

Comment: @Nifle: Programs can save files in "Program Files". Explorer just doesn't let the user see the contents by default.

Comment: @harrymc - No you can't. Read up on `Folder Virtualization` in vista. Any changes to files or new files written en up somewhere under `Users\...\Appdata` and thus can't be found if you search under `Program Files`